# Error in code: "This is a function it cannot be applied"

Tags: ocaml

I am new to Ocaml. I am unsure why the following does not work:

```
    let nDivM m n = n/m
    let rec decimalToM m n = if (n < m) then n+n
    else ((n mod m) * n) + decimalToM(m nDivM)
```

The above is meant to be a base converter (M is the base). I expected an int, but right now it does not run.

Comment: Hi @Alex and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you add a little more detail, what you have already figured out, so that it saves time when people help you?

Comment: I'm getting "This is *not* a function; it cannot be applied." Which makes a lot more sense than the error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in this subexpression:

```
decimalToM(m nDivM)
```

The subexpression `(m nDivM)` is syntactically a call to `m` as a function, passing `nDivM` as the parameter.

Since `nDivM` is a function, you can't fix this up completely just by moving the parentheses around. It seems to me you need to supply some arguments for `nDivM`. Then you should make sure your parentheses are right.

If `f` is a function of two arguments, then the way to call it in OCaml is: `f x y`. Note that there are no parentheses required (unless `x` or `y` is a more complex expression).